# Redirect from /index.html, /index.php and /index to root

Tags: .htaccess, modx

kitten :)
How to make at the same time a redirect from /index.html, /index.php and / index to root?

I tried this code

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.html 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ /$1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

but with this code administrative panel MODX ceases to work normally

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a Redirect

```
Redirect /index /
```

This will redirect **/index/anyPath** to root.